# nhibernate softdelete where override

Tags: nhibernate, soft-delete

Ok,
In my solution I have implemented softdeletes by setting IsDeleted to true instead of deleting an entity.

I also added the Where IsDeleted=false in the class Mapings.

Now all my select queries get executed with the where that restricts the result to those that are not deleted.

But now in specific queries i need to show those that are deleted tool.
How can I override this behavior in some queries?

Please help.
Thanks
Luka

Comment: can you post the relevant parts of your mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would instead advice you to implement the functionality using filters instead.

You could enable this filter on all entities with IsDeleted column, and then explicitly disable the filter when you want to search for all records.

It is quite similar to what is described here: [NHibernate: Creating a criteria which applies for all queries on a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358744/nhibernate-creating-a-criteria-which-applies-for-all-queries-on-a-table)

Answer (score 1):

+1 filter's work great for scenario's exactly like that but keep in mind they do not work on many-to-one, one-to-one associations.

So for the case of the classes `Foo` and `Bar` where `Bar` is soft-deleted and `Foo` points to `Bar` and the association is mapped (ie. `Foo.Bar`) if you fetch Foo and Bar is soft deleted the entity will still be hydrated.

This is problematic when you contain logic like

```
if (Foo.Bar != null) {
   //will never execute
}
```

You can change this behavior by making a trivial change on the library, i have written a post on
http://savale.blogspot.com/2010/01/enabling-filters-on-mapped-entities.html that shows how to do that. It describes the opration for v2.1.2 but it's similar for v3.0+ pf NHibernate